# php : get tmp size

Tags: php, filesize, tmp

how to get tmp size

my code

```
filesize('/tmp/phpn3jaaQ');
```

error

> PHP Warning:  filesize() [function.filesize]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 524 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /home/script/file.php on line 2

Answer (score 2):

You can't use file handling / management functions in [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) for files not owned by the same UID as the script.

Turn off safe mode and your code should work.

Edit: Clarified previous statement regarding file handling.

Another note, safe mode is deprecated as of PHP 5.3, meaning it will not be available in a future version. You should avoid using it and certainly not rely on it.

Comment: "You can't use file management functions in safe mode." --- why do you think so?

Comment: @Phil Brown: `<?php var_dump(filesize('set.php'), ini_get('safe_mode'));` // int(78) string(1) "1" Everybody lies. Comments in the php manual is the thing I advice never to trust.

Comment: @Phil Brown: I cannot agree with the current answer. Issue is not in the safe mode, but in the developer, who cannot work with safe mode and who cannot read error messages. Sorry, but you're confusing newbies, downvoted.

Comment: @zerkms I've clarified my answer. In your example, are the calling script and `set.php` owned by the same UID?

Comment: @Phil Brown: sure. And your answer did not reflect this fact. Now it is. Btw, I still don't agree with solution. He should not (and probably is not able to) turn off safe mode, but he should just set proper file owners.

Comment: @zerkms He / his host should turn off safe mode (if possible) as it is now deprecated

Comment: @Phil Brown: I bet his hosting provider never do this ;-) Btw, I've re-voted to +1

Comment: @zerkms Along with `magic_quotes_gpc` and `register_globals` ;) Thanks for the upvote. Apologies for the original blunt answer.

Comment: @Phil Brown: yeah, but providers will not risc to migrate to 5.3 in near year (or even more). There are too much clients whose scripts will be broken after such upgrade.